# How to create a new database in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I installed "SQL Server 2005 Express Edition" and "SQL Server Management Studio Express" on a Windows 7 Box.

When I try to create a new database in Management Studio I get this error message:

```
Create failed for Database 'MyDatabase'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262)
```

How do I create a new database in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1):

### Create a new database in SQL Server 2005:

Start SQL Server Management Studio as administrator by right clicking the icon and choosing "run as administrator".

Connect to the database engine with username/password.

Right click the folder that says: "Databases", and choose "New Database", see the following screenshot:

[image]

You get this screen, enter your database name of 'foobar'.

[image]

Click OK.  Now look under databases folder to see your new foobar database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click SQL Management studio icon and run it as administrator.  If you are a member of sysadmin group then you should be able to right click "Databases" folder and choose "New Database", then follow onscreen instructions.